# Install mac os x from time machine

Tags: macos, time-machine, mac-mini, macos-highsierra

I have a MacBook pro that I backup using time machine. I need to set up a mac mini but I want the same programs and settings I have on my MacBook. Will it be ok if I install it from the MacBook’s time machine backup? Will it cause any compatibility issues on the mini?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

macOS installs always include all the pieces needed to run any Mac that is supported by that version of the OS. So let’s say your MacBook is on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 and High Sierra also supports your Mac mini: you’d be fine.

Plus, you can use Migration Assisitant to migrate all your files and settings from a Time Machine backup to a new machine without migrating the OS itself. For best results, update both machines to the latest version of macOS that they can both run, before doing the migration.

Comment: It’s a mac mini late 2014 that supports high sierra. Can I do it during installation?

Comment: @blade Yes, there’s a step during the post-install/first-boot setup assistant that asks if you want to migrate stuff from a Time Machine backup or another Mac. Use that.